# Scraping with jsonlite library

Tags: r, web-scraping, jsonlite

I´m trying to scrape a webpage using jsonlite library as it follows:

```
page <- jsonlite::fromJSON("http://divulgacandcontas.tse.jus.br/divulga/rest/v1/candidatura/buscar/2018/GO/2022802018/candidato/90000609234")
data <- dplyr::bind_rows(page)
```

The command returns me a list of 63, but i can't get the header from this list, therefore the bind_rows command is not working. If i use the str command it prints both data and header:

```
str(page)

#List of 63
#$ id                              : num 9e+10
(...)
```

Does anyone know how can I attribute to an object both data and header?

Comment: See [httr](http://httr.r-lib.org/)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your `List of 63` is just that, a list of mostly "atomic" (char/numeric) elements with some complex and length 0 elements. There's nothing to "bind", per-se. Do you want the `bens` element? `cargo` element? `partido`? `eleicao`? It's likely this question will get closed unless you can provide more information on what you're trying to accomplish.